# How to log Apache HTTP Client traffic as Allure reports?

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x, allure

I would like Apache HTTP Client requests and responses to be logged in [Allure Reports](http://allure.qatools.ru/) as attachments.

In traditional logging frameworks like logback, I do it in the following way:

```
<logger name="org.apache.http.wire" level="DEBUG">
```

How do I do it in Allure?

Comment: I don't know is there any ready-to-use integration at the moment. But Allure Team is going to add it. See https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-java/pull/51